# Embed Facebook post on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried several ways to config my app in order to display an embed post with `Facebook JS SDK` but no success.

#### Here is my config

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute",
        "ngAnimate","digitalfondue.dftabmenu"]);

    app.controller("ViewCtrl", function($scope) {

    });
    app.config(function($routeProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.

    when("/inicio", {

    templateUrl: "inicio.phtml",
          controller: "inicioCtrl",
          animate: "slideLeft"
        }).
     when("/anyotherpage", {

    templateUrl: "anyotherpage.phtml",
          controller: "anyotherpageCtrl",
          animate: "slideLeft"
        }).   
    otherwise({redirectTo: "/inicio"});
    }
    )
```

#### And my Facebook JS SDK

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_CO/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=627634673965707";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

#### The embed post

```
<div class="fb-post" data-href="$posturl" data-width="350">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="$posturl">
        <p></p>
        Publicado Por
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/herbalistas">Herbalist</a> el <a href="$posturl"></a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```